How can I get a ‘dispatch id’ in task shader called by vkCmdDrawMeshTasksIndirectEXT?
I fill VkDrawMeshTasksIndirectCommandEXT in one compute shader, then invoke once vkCmdDrawMeshTasksIndirectEXT to draw every thing.
The problem is that I don't know which instance, which meshlet I am processing in task shader.(If use vertex shader draw pipeline, I can use gl_InstanceID to load the instance data).
If there are something like gl_DispatchID can use in task shader will help a lot.
